# Force use 1.9.8 PhantomJS with karma-phantomjs-launcher

Tags: npm, phantomjs, karma-runner

I have a build process... One of the steps is running test with `Karma` on `PhantomJS`. Unfortunatelly `karma-phantomjs-launcher` automatically fetches `"phantomjs-prebuilt": ">=1.9"`, and this fetches latest PhantomJS (2.1.1) from the internet. And on linux machines I get this error:

```
[11:21:15][Step 1/1] > gom-filters@1.0.4 test /sbclocal/apps/BuildAgent/work/5d1d4b9ee540b3ac

[11:21:15][Step 1/1] > karma start test/karma.conf.js --single-run --browsers PhantomJS

[11:21:15][Step 1/1] 

[11:21:17][Step 1/1] 16 03 2016 11:21:17.569:INFO [karma]: Karma v0.13.21 server started at http://localhost:9876/

[11:21:17][Step 1/1] 16 03 2016 11:21:17.583:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS

[11:21:17][Step 1/1] 16 03 2016 11:21:17.603:ERROR [phantomjs.launcher]: /sbclocal/apps/BuildAgent/work/5d1d4b9ee540b3ac/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs: /usr/lib64/libz.so.1: no version information available (required by /sbclocal/apps/BuildAgent/work/5d1d4b9ee540b3ac/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs)

[11:21:17][Step 1/1] /sbclocal/apps/BuildAgent/work/5d1d4b9ee540b3ac/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found (required by /sbclocal/apps/BuildAgent/work/5d1d4b9ee540b3ac/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs)

[11:21:17][Step 1/1] /sbclocal/apps/BuildAgent/work/5d1d4b9ee540b3ac/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /sbclocal/apps/BuildAgent/work/5d1d4b9ee540b3ac/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs)

[11:21:17][Step 1/1] /sbclocal/apps/BuildAgent/work/5d1d4b9ee540b3ac/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.9' not found (required by /sbclocal/apps/BuildAgent/work/5d1d4b9ee540b3ac/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs)

[11:21:17][Step 1/1] /sbclocal/apps/BuildAgent/work/5d1d4b9ee540b3ac/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.10' not found (required by /sbclocal/apps/BuildAgent/work/5d1d4b9ee540b3ac/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs)

[11:21:17][Step 1/1] /sbclocal/apps/BuildAgent/work/5d1d4b9ee540b3ac/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.7' not found (required by /sbclocal/apps/BuildAgent/work/5d1d4b9ee540b3ac/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs)
```

I tried to manually launch PhantomJS 1.9.8 and it worked fine.

Is there a way to enforce download 1.9.8 instead of latest (2.1.1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specyfing PhantomJS dependency version explicitly to 1.9.8 in package.json solved the issue.

Comment: I also had to change version of `karma-phantomjs-launcher` to `^0.2.3`. Now it works, thanks!

Comment: @dragonfly Can you please show the line you mention of package.json? Thanks